# SQL - Hide column that I'm counting?

Tags: sql

I want to hide the column that I'm counting.
It looks like this:

```
SELECT name, room, COUNT(seats) AS seats...
```

I only want to show `name` and `room` when executing though. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Why do you count the seats if you don't want to show them? If you want to use it i, e.g. in `ORDER BY` you don't have to put them into the Select-list: `ORDER BY COUNT(seats) DESC`

Comment: Then why select it in the first place?

Comment: Do you want to hide seats? Or the count of seats? If the first, it will be hidden automatically because you will only be grouping by name and room.

Comment: My guess is he wants to be able to query the # of seats but doesn't want it to show in the results. That would have to be done when displaying the data. I assume its some web page or winform.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use aggregated function `COUNT()` you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, room
```

After read your comment, to select the room with more seats:

```
SELECT name, room
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name, room
ORDER BY COUNT(seats) DESC
LIMIT 1  -- This is postgres/mysql, sql server use TOP
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the count in a subquery:

```
select name, room from (
select name, room, count(seats) as seats
from ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to use the count of room's someplace?  Perhaps you're looking to include it in a having statement?

```
SELECT name, room
FROM TableName
GROUP BY seats,name,room
HAVING COUNT(seats) > 1;
```

EDIT:

```
select top 1 name, room
group by seats,name,room
order by count(seats) desc
```

Comment: You can't select `name` and `room` since they aren't in the `GROUP BY`